# foreach loop on ungrouped xml tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

As per my requirement I cant group them. please help me find the solution

**Note:** xslt 1.0

**XML**

```
<item_title>item1</item_title>
<item_title>item2</item_title>
<item_title>item3</item_title>

<item_description>description1</item_description>
<item_description>description2</item_description>
<item_description>description3</item_description>
```

**output needed:**

```
 <div class="item">
    <div class="item_title">item1</div>
    <div class="item_content">description1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <div class="item_title">item2</div>
    <div class="item_content">description2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <div class="item_title">item3</div>
    <div class="item_content">description3</div>
 </div>
```

**What I tried:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="item_title">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_title">
           <xsl:value-of select="item_title[position()]"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="item_content">
            <xsl:value-of select="item_description[position()]"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: my output is html not xml

Comment: HTML can be thought of as a subset of XML. You can use any HTML tag in XML.

Comment: You cannot use `position()` in a predicate like that; it loses the context. Put it into a variable first and use the variable.

Comment: I found a better way and posted it as answer..

Comment: "*I found a better way.*" No, you haven't.  ;-)

Comment: the example you people have given are long and creepy,,,

Comment: *I* have not given any examples. BTW, this is **not** really a grouping question.

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its previous version - otherwise my comment will not make sense.

Comment: fine.....I was not able frame the title properly..can modify it to something better as per question

Comment: I meant that the references to other questions regarding grouping are irrelevant to the issue here.

Comment: yes you are right..I was confused with the answers which they provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way which i find better as per my requirement:

**calling the iterative function:**

```
<xsl:call-template name="iterative">
    <xsl:with-param name="num" select="1" />
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(item_title)" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

**declaring a templating:**

```
<xsl:template name="iterative">
<xsl:param name="num" />
<xsl:param name="count" />
<xsl:if test="not($num = $count+1)">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_title">
           <span class="icon_plus">+</span>
           <span class="icon_minus">–</span>
           <xsl:value-of select="item_title[$num]"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="item_content">
            <xsl:value-of select="item_description[$num]"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:call-template name="iterative">
        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```